# Search sheet for multiple values at a single time

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-match

I've an Excel sheet with almost 30,000 rows and I have a list to be searched within the Excel of size 100 values. I don't want to search manually each time.

How can I perform a search of all these 100 values at a single go?

Comment: Some information about the data to be search (layout, etc) would be great. Otherwise, google for `vlookup`

Comment: What result do you want from the values - a count or sum?

Comment: Highlight the found ones.

Comment: Are the values numbers or text?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your longer list is in ColumnA and your shorter one is a named range `My100List`, in B1 and copied down to suit:

```
=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(A1,My100List,0)),"","listed")
```

then filter ColumnB to select `listed`.

*Edit re comment:*

Select ColumnA and apply a Conditional Formatting formula rule of:

```
=MATCH(A1,My100List,0)>0
```

with fill colour of choice.